# Why was this edit rejected that was improved?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

It is just a rejected edit, but I thought I should ask about it.

My Edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9560572

Original

[PHP MySQL query returning zero results when table has data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664321/php-mysql-query-returning-zero-results-when-table-has-data)

You see all that mess of code? That is what I fixed. I only uppercased PHP because of the six character limit.

Comment: I did not review this suggested edit but you added "HTML/PHP CODE:" in code format when it should not have been.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was the reviewer that rejected your edit. I was overly tired at the time and probably should have been sleeping. I meant to press <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> to remove the indentation before "*HTML/PHP CODE*" and didn't realize until right now that I had chosen <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>. The important thing is that the edit was applied.

Sorry, my bad. I'll do my best not to let it happen again.

Comment: Ah, it's all good.